# gnome panel items

Tags: gnome, system-tray

testing out gnome to see if it may be better for me. I am used to using Unity on 13.04 by now but I tried to install gnome and get used to that and see how it goes.

I am trying to get notification items, like Pidgin, Rhythmbox, keepass2, ect, to the notifications area like in Unity. but I only see settings, battery, wifi, bluetooth, and audio. how do I get my the others to start there.

Answer (score 0):

Rhythmbox doesn't put an icon in the Notification Area, instead it puts the icon in the Indicator Applet, so add that to your panel:

Right-click on an empty space in the panel, select 'Add to panel...', and drag the Indicator Applet to your panel.

Comment: I have no right click option, alt-rightclick, super-alt-right, ctrl, nothing, tried multiple keystroke combos according to things I found on google. gnome-shell 3.8.3